# Angular 2 - Prevent click on child when clicked on parent element?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I clicked on anchor tag `onClick` function is called but its child elements onclick function also called with it. I want to prevent this if parent element is clicked then why its child elements clicked with it.

Here is the code:

```
<li *ngFor = "let category of categories">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);"  (click)="toggle($event);">
        <span class="ah-pull-left" style="padding: 7px 10px;font-size: 14px;">
            <span class="ah-hexa">C</span>
        </span>
        <span class="ah-pull-left">{{category.title}}</span>
        <span class="ah-pull-right ah-sidebar-down-arrow" *ngIf = "category.submenu.length > 0"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </a>
      <div id="{{category.id}}" class="ah-sidebar-sub-menu" *ngIf = "category.submenu">
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor = "let subcategory of category.submenu">
                  <a href="{{subcategory.link}}">
                    <span class="ah-pull-left" style="font-size: 14px;">
                        <span class="ah-hexa">{{subcategory.title.charAt(0)}}</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ah-pull-left">{{subcategory.title}}</span>
                    </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

**.ts**

```
toggle(e) {
    if(e.target || e.srcElement || e.currentTarget){
        console.log(e.target.parentNode)
    }
}
```

**Output in browser console window:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**:

In my case below code works:

```
<a #myElement href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{category.id}}" (click)="onClick(myElement.id);">
```

But I don't know how `#myElement` is preventing child elements to be clicked. BTW this is working fine and I'm getting the actual element on which I had clicked.

Here is my .html code:

```
<li *ngFor = "let category of categories">
      <a #myElement href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{category.id}}" (click)="onClick(myElement.id);">
        <span class="ah-pull-left" style="padding: 7px 10px;font-size: 14px;">
            <span class="ah-hexa">C</span>
        </span>
        <span class="ah-pull-left">{{category.title}}</span>
        <span class="ah-pull-right ah-sidebar-down-arrow" *ngIf = "category.submenu.length > 0"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </a>
      <div  class="ah-sidebar-sub-menu" *ngIf = "category.submenu" style="display: none">
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor = "let subcategory of category.submenu">
                  <a href="{{subcategory.link}}">
                    <span class="ah-pull-left" style="font-size: 14px;">
                        <span class="ah-hexa">{{subcategory.title.charAt(0)}}</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ah-pull-left">{{subcategory.title}}</span>
                    </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Here is my .ts code:

```
onClick(e) {
    console.log('HTML Element ID: ' + e);
}
```

Comment: Click events are registered on the element that was actually clicked. But it will bubble upward until it finds an element that has an event handler. This is why `event.target`is the child element. If you do `onClick($event, myElement.id)` you will still see the child element. Did not know `#myElement` worked inside a ng-for loop. Then you could do `#myElement` and `onClick(myElement)`. Do not think you need the `id="{{category.id}}"` part unless you are using it for something else.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could send the source element in to the onClickHandler like this.

```js
function onClickA(event, element) {
  console.log(event, element);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a onclick="onClickA(event, this)">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>World</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: The `this` keyword get my component not the clicked element. I don't know what is wrong there? If I clicked on anchor tag then why other element click event also calling? How to prevent this and get only clicked element.

Comment: Sorry I did not know. It looks like with angular you are not supposed to  change DOM-elements outside the framework. What are you actually trying to do? Toggle the visibility of the a-tag? Could you not use ng-if statment instead? `*ngIf="showLink()"` and in code `showLink(){ return this.isLinkVisible; }` and set it in the event handler `onClickLink(){ this.isLinkVisible = !this.isLinkVisible; }`?

Comment: You could also get the a-tag by using the `event.path` property. Iterate over the list and find the first element with an onclick handler. That should be you a-tag. It is kind of hacky but it will work I think.

Comment: Appreciate your answers but I found my answer and post it here too. Also I do some modification in my question for better understanding have a look on that. Second thing about `*ngIf`, As I have submenus in my sidebar navigation and that's why I need to get the ID of my submenu parent element so I can toggle it.